# Nginx rewrite equivalent to Apache RewriteRule that converts URL params into QueryString key/value pair

Tags: php, apache, nginx, laravel-forge

I'm performing a migration from an Apache server to Nginx and missed a `.htaccess` file that performs a rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ routes.php?params=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

For example, this endpoint `example.com/api/v1/param1/param2/param3` would be rewritten as `https://example.com/api/v1/routes.php?params=/param1/param2/param3`

Can someone confirm that this is the correct equivalent for Nginx before I re-attempt the migration?

```
rewrite "(?i)^(.*)$" routes.php?params=$1
```

and is this how it would be used in the config file since `/api/v1` is the only path that requires the rewrite?

```
location /api/v1 {
  rewrite "(?i)^(.*)$" routes.php?params=$1
}
```

**UPDATE**

Adding this to the conf file in Laravel Forge appears to just break the application and prevents displaying any views.  Instead, it says `This site can’t be reached example.com refused to connect.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`, and your regular expressions do not attempt to remove the `/api/v1/` prefix before appending the parameter list.

Try:

```
location /api/v1 {
    rewrite ^/api/v1(/.*)$ /api/v1/routes.php?params=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: That's actually a typo. It was supposed to be `/api/v1` and that's where routes.php is located.  What are the changes required for using `/api/v1`?  I've never been good at Regex

Comment: If `routes.php` is located in the subfolder `api/v1/`, the URL in your question should be `https://example.com/api/v1/routes.php?params=/param1/param2/param3` - is that right?

Comment: Yah, routes would have that exact querystring.  Sorry, I was trying to keep the example in the question as simple as possible, but then accidentally mixed it with what it looks like in the actual application.